# Method behavior with codeigniter parameters

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Needing help understanding codeigniter 3 behavior

I'm not understanding the controller behavior very well and I ask for help

```
class Simulado extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct(){

        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('funcoes_helper');
        $this->load->helper('file');            
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->library('controle_acesso');
        $this->load->model('resumoapp_model', 'resumo');
        $this->load->model('homeapp_model', 'homeapp');
        $this->load->model('simulado_model', 'simulado');       

        //permissão para acessar app
        $this->controle_acesso->acesso();

        $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
        
    }

    public function index() { 

        $dados = '0'//todas as materias;
        $bdinsert = $this->simulado->set_bd($dados);

        $this->load->view('prova',$dados)

    }

    public function materia () { 
                        
        $dados = 1; //idamateria
        $bdinsert = $this->simulado->set_bd($dados);
        $this->load->view('prova',$dados)

    }
}
```

model

```
public function set_bd ($dados) {           

            $data = [
                'id_mat' = $dados
            ];

            $this->db->insert('simulados', $data);
    }
```

routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
$route['404_override'] = 'my404';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
$route['app'] = "/app/home";
$route['site'] = "/home";
```

when accessed through the link http://localhost/escola/app/simulado, the system behaves in the desired way, it writes the value zero once in the database, for example.

accessing the url we have the method of the class, simulated, http://localhost/escola/app/simulado/materia/1/exatas-matematica calls the method in the correct way, but when writing to the database it writes the code of the matter.

I did a test and put the same code of the article method in the index and called the url, and it worked perfectly, writing only once the code of the article in the database.

I need to know why it is recording 3 times in the database when accessing the url is a method of the class and has parameters.

Comment: Hello lelopes, your question is kind of vague, as in there's nothing in the provided code that should write anything to a database. Are you sure you're using the right terminology?

Comment: @KayAngevare yes, I simplified the code because it is too big. but the above demo is my real scenario, test with above simplified code and the error also occurred, writing 3 times to the database. if necessary edit and put the model code.

Comment: This route `http://localhost/escola/app/simulado/materia/1/exatas-matematica` does not seem to match any of the methods in the controller you've posted. Not sure in which folder your CodeIgniter installation is, but since the controller you've posted is called `Simulado`, I would expect to see a method in there called `materia` that handles this url (unless a different route is specified in `routes.php`, which does not seem to be the case). Are you sure you're looking at the right controller/method?

Comment: @Marleen you are correct, correct the name of the method, I had spelled it wrong. thanks. even with continuous observation with the problem